# If $ z_{0}=x_{0}+iy_{0}$ satisfy the equation $2\left|z_{0}\right|^2=r^2+2.$ Then $\left|\alpha \right| = $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Let a Complex no. $\alpha$ and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\bar{\alpha}}$ lie on the Circles $\left|z-z_{0}\right|=r$ and $\left|z-z_{0}\right|=4r^2$ respectively.
>
> If $\displaystyle z_{0}=x_{0}+iy_{0}$ satisfy the equation $2\left|z_{0}\right|^2=r^2+2.$ Then $\left|\alpha \right| = $

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ If $\alpha$ lies on $\left|z-z_{0}\right|^2 = r^2\;,$ Then Put $z=\alpha$ in Given equation.

So We get $\left|\alpha-z_{0}\right|^2=r^2.......................................................(1)$

Similarly If $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\bar{\alpha}}$ lies on $\left|z-z_{0}\right|^2 = 4r^2\;,$ Then Put $\displaystyle z=\frac{1}{\bar{\alpha}}$ in Given equation.

So We get $\displaystyle \left|\frac{1}{\bar{\alpha}}-z_{0}\right|^2=4r^2\Rightarrow \left|1-\bar{\alpha}z_{0}\right|^2=4r^2 \cdot \left|\bar{\alpha}\right|^2=4r^2 \cdot \left|\alpha\right|^2.....................(2)$

Now Subtract $(2)$ from $(1)\;,$ We Get....

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \left|\alpha-z_{0} \right|^2 -\left|1-\bar{\alpha}z_{0}\right|^2=r^2-4r^2 \left|\alpha \right|^2$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \left|\alpha \right|^2+\left|z_{0}\right|^2-\alpha \bar{z_{0}}-\bar{\alpha}z_{0}-1-\left|\alpha\right|^2\left|z_{0}\right|^2+\alpha \bar{z_{0}}+\bar{\alpha}z_{0}=r^2-4r^2\left|\alpha \right|^2$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \left|\alpha \right|^2-1+\left|z_{0}\right|^2-\left|\alpha\right|^2\left|z_{0}\right|^2=r^2-4r^2\left|\alpha^2\right|$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \Bigg(\left|z_{0}^2\right|-1 \Bigg)\cdot \left(1-\left|\alpha ^2\right|\right)=r^2-4r^2 \left|\alpha\right|^2$

Now Using $\displaystyle \left|z_{0}\right|^2 = \left(\frac{r^2+2}{2}\right).$ and Put into above above equation.

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \Bigg(\frac{r^2}{2}\Bigg)\cdot\left(1-\left|\alpha ^2\right|\right)=r^2-4r^2 \left|\alpha\right|^2 $

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \left(r^2\right)\cdot \left(1-\left|\alpha ^2\right|\right)=2r^2-8r^2 \left|\alpha\right|^2.$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow r^2-r^2\left|\alpha \right|^2=2r^2-8r^2 \left|\alpha\right|^2$

So we get  $\displaystyle 7r^2 \left|\alpha \right|^2 = r^2\Rightarrow \left|\alpha\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}$.

My Question is can we solve the above question any other method,

If yes then please explain me.

Thanks.

Comment: @juantheron: In the question, you write that $\frac{1}{\bar\alpha}$ lies on the circle $|z-z_0|=4r^2$. But in your solution, you write "if $\frac{1}{\bar\alpha}$ lies on $|z-z_0|\color{red}{^2}=4r^2$". Which is true?